# How to get whole object as an response after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have simple JavaScript snippet:

```
var obrazek = [{nazwa: "Sniadanie", wiek: 100, autor: "Alicja"},{nazwa: "Kolacja", wiek: 10, autor: "Misiek"}];

function galeria(nazwa, wsad) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.wsad = wsad;
    this.print = function(element) {
        for (var i=0;i<this.wsad.length;i++) {
            var text = "<li>"+this.wsad[i].nazwa+"</li>"
            element.append(text);
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    gal = new galeria('test', obrazek);
    gal.print($('#galeriaTest'))
});
```

It gives me:

```
<ul id="galeriaTest>
    <li>Sniadanie</li>
    <li>Kolacja</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is simple method that will return object after click event:

```
Object { nazwa="Sniadanie", wiek=100, autor="Alicja"} (in FireBug)
```

How to code it?

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but I suggest you to capitalize your constructor functions' names, and move methods to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As long as your data set is static**, you can just associate the object to the DOM element using the `data()` function.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2bwwj/).

If your data set is dynamic, you could still associate a reference to the `Galeria` and some ID type of information to get a similar albeit improved result.

Comment: Great! It is what I was looking for. Could you tell me what you mean by dynamic data?

Comment: I just meant that if your data set is updating asynchronously, you need to make sure that references to it stay in sync. For instance, you wouldn't want an object in your Galeria replaced with another one, but have the list item still referencing the old object. But in many cases, this isn't something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").on('click', function(e){
   console.log( obrazek );  // would put object in a console, you can check it via firebug
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, I wasn't very precise. I want to see only the clicked object